What is the lift to drag ratio of Starship?
By watching the live feed of IFT-4, its pretty obvious that Starship does not actually re-enter in the "skydiver" position, but rather at an AoA of around 45°. There is no doubt that this is a lifting trajectory. But how much lift is produced?

89°AoA would also be lifting

What surprised me was how it seemed to fly almost level for nearly three minutes at 68 km which either was some incredible gliding or else the telemetry was not correct. I never heard or read anyone mentioning this during or since. It took 33 seconds for it to drop from 69 km to 68 km, but then starting at T+50:41 it stayed at 68 km for 2 minutes 53 seconds before reaching 67 km. It then took only 23 seconds to go from 67 km to 66 km. I thought maybe the telemetry was frozen but during its time at 68 km the speed dropped from 24,900 to 22,200 km/h. On the coms it said it was experiencing 0.5 g

@user721108 - I never said it couldn't, I said I have not heard any mention of it which is somewhat surprising if it glided nearly level for nearly three minutes that this hasn't been mentioned somewhere, at least not that I have come across. Thus my theory that maybe the telemetry was incorrect.

imo telemetry was correct. No clue why that skip entry event wasn't talked about live, since it should be something interesting to tell about while happening

We can discuss all day the reasons and possibilities for a 3 minute level glide during reentry, which I would be all for. But it's surprising that Starship glided nearly level for three minutes and no one is talking about it, when every nut and bolt and every movement of Starship, even lifts on and off the OLM is discussed in minutia. Would love to hear some confirmation from SpaceX, or find some analysis somewhere of the livestream telemetry. My quick observations are that as it approached 70 km the AOA increased from 61% to 67%. Then early in its 68 km glide the nose steadily lowered to 54%.

@StevePemberton we know virtually nothing about how Starship's reentry guidance profile looks. The skydiver orientation thing was always meant to describe terminal descent, I think the problem was that the control mode was the same during reentry, and so you see people including Elon mention it's in skydiver mode, and people like us conflating that to mean strict 90 deg AoA throughout reentry.

@StevePemberton as for the glide, your observation that the AOA decreases during the 70km glide seems physically consistent. As to why they chose this, I doubt anyone can say. We only have one (two?) example of publicly released info on re-entry guidance, i.e. Shuttle reentry guidance, and two if you believe that Buran used a similar profile. (1/2)

@StevePemberton The Shuttle did not have a constant altitude phase, but this was because it had a limited ability to modulate drag by varying AoA, so it had to use its descent rate to control deceleration. With Starship things may be different, since it can simply vary flap deployment to modulate drag. It's entirely possible that, for simplicity, Starship entry guidance uses AoA to control lift and thus maintain 70km, while using flap deployment to modulate drag, until it reaches some transition condition whereupon it enters true skydiver mode. (2/2)

@dsdy120 - In the case of Apollo skip entry referred to the upward climb even though they didn’t actually leave the atmosphere. The Starship livestream telemetry was only granular to 1 km, so maybe for example maybe there was a “mini-skip” from say 68,100 m back up to 68,900 m, then back down again through 68,000 m, in other words a 0.8 km skip. But even that would be a lot more shallow than Apollo, which other than Apollo 11 was fairly flat. For example Apollo 10 did about a 5 km skip when it climbed from 56 km back up to 61 km.

@StevePemberton It's certainly possible. My angle was more towards how this profile was controlled. Apollo and Shuttle used bank angle to modify descent rate, descent rate to modify drag, and drag to modify landing location, so the altitude profile matters immensely and is likely to adopt a complex physics-defined curve. The Shuttle had to do this because it could not deviate from its design alpha without losing control, while the Apollo CM couldn't modulate its alpha at all. Starship conversely might get away with an artifically flat profile because its flaps can make up the difference.

One reference here gives 1.0 L/D at 45 degrees, although I don't know why, because the max is 1.5 from the source:
https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=56619.0
The source is independent analysis, and I don't have the full text. Looking for similar sources, this is a more proper publication from another Chinese institution
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Zian-Wang-5/publication/363311418_Performance_Analysis_on_the_Small-Scale_Reusable_Launch_Vehicle/links/6317595861e4553b956dab02/Performance-Analysis-on-the-Small-Scale-Reusable-Launch-Vehicle.pdf
That gives a max value of 3 at the optimum of 40 degrees.
For reference the Shuttle is often quoted at 1.5, and the X-41 might be as much as 3. However, Starship looks much much more like the Shuttle than the X-41, and because of that I trust the 1.5 number much more. What's also likely is that the paper giving the 3 did a less-than-hypersonic or low-hypersonic analysis.
There are reasons you might not even want the maximum L/D. If it were too high, the craft could go into a skip, which might lead to even worse heating. Assuming the telemetry was correct, there is a meaningful chance they actively changed angle in order to hold altitude constant, which means running at L/D lower than optimum for most of the constant-altitude coasting time.
Numbers from the company are not obviously available, so everything you read will be informed speculation, at best.

1.5 is not a very good number for the shuttle orbiter. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/105672/31936
